# Blank page, nothing but plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin (contact form) which uses a shortcode for placement on pages.

How can I get a page that has nothing else on it besides the plugin (no header, footer, navbar, sidebar, etc)?

I am using the Twenty Eleven theme.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: create an according template for your *contact page* and assign that template to your *contact page* in Wordpress' admin area.

If you need a more detailed *"How To"*, check:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates